# Hive Query dumping issue

Tags: hadoop, hive, hdfs

I am facing difficulties in getting the `dump(text file delimited by ^)` for a Query in hive for my project -sentimental analysis in stock market using twitter.

The query which should fetch me an output in hdfs or local file-system is given below:

```
hive> select t.cmpname,t.datecol,t.tweet,st.diff FROM tweet t LEFT OUTER JOIN  stock st ON(t.datecol = st.datecol AND lower(t.cmpname) = lower(st.cmpname));
```

The query produces the correct output but when I try dumping it in hdfs it gives me an error.

I ran through various other solutions given in stackoverflow for dumping but I was not able to find an appropriate solution which suits me.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT OVERWRITE DIRECTORY '/path/to/dir'
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '^'
SELECT t.cmpname,t.datecol,t.tweet,st.diff FROM tweet t LEFT OUTER JOIN stock st
    ON(t.datecol = st.datecol AND lower(t.cmpname) = lower(st.cmpname));
```